# Select associated attributes in join in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, activerecord, left-join

app/models/user.rb

```
has_one :user_detail
```

app/models/user_detail.rb
    belongs_to :user

When I query

```
User.active.
  select('users.id, users.first_name, users.last_name,user_details.unit_number').
  joins('LEFT JOIN user_details ON users.id = user_details.user_id').
  where(:property_id => params[:id])
```

It gives me only user model columns, not giving `user_details.unit_number`. How I get this?

I am doing this

```
users = User.active.select('users.id, users.first_name, users.last_name, user_details.unit_number').joins('LEFT JOIN user_details ON users.id = user_details.user_id').where(:property_id => params[:id])

users_list = users.as_json(:only => [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :unit_number)
```

Answer (score 2):

By using `select`, you have stripped-down ActiveRecord objects, especially they have no longer the relation to your `user_detail`

You can make the `user_detail` attributs available in your `user` objects by using `as` in the `select` statement

```
User.active.
  select('users.id, users.first_name, users.last_name, user_details.unit_number as unit_number').
  joins('LEFT JOIN user_details ON users.id = user_details.user_id').
  where(:property_id => params[:id])
```

Then you should be able to access the information like it is a normal attribute of the user (and not of user_detail)

Comment: But I want it witihn result.Any possibility of that?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean with "in the result". How are you using the query?

Comment: Meanz I want get all user_details.unit_number within first query

Comment: How are you using the query? Because there seem something that you have not understood.

Comment: Then the query should work, I'm just not sure if the users.as_json() will include the "new" unit_number attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I would use built-in Rails tools for this ([`includes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes) in this case):

```
users = User.active.includes(:user_detail).where(property_id: params[:id])
```

And now you can call, for example:

```
users.first.user_detail.unit_number
```

and you're guaranteed you don't have N + 1 problem

Comment: But it is recommended that with where clause not use include.

Comment: Where is it recommended?

Comment: @MarekLipka It's right here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations
so use in this case its better  `User.joins(:user_detail).where(user_detail: { property_id: params[:id]})
 `